# Пассивный процесс

Tags: java

У меня есть приложение(допустим игра), у игры есть какое-то меню, которое содержит две кнопки - игра и радио. При нажатии кнопки игра, мы попадаем в игру, а при нажатии радио открывается новое окно в котором идёт непрерывная игра музыки.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда мы нажимали кнопку радио запускался какой-то "пассивный" процесс(т.е. открывалось окно с радио) и в окне родителе мы могли бы продолжить работу(т.е. нажать на кнопку игра и играть). На данный момент, после нажатия кнопки радио, родитель полностью не отвечает на действия, а музыка играет.

Мне нужно, чтобы я мог запустить какой-то бесконечный цикл и оставить его фоновым.

Comment: Запустите дополнительный поток.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, Вы не представляете, как вы мне помогли! Спасибо вам!!!)